# How can i get people who open my website be redirected to the homepage immediatly?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make my website for school and my layout is almost done. I'm just trying to make it so when you open the HTML file it goes to the home page, but i have no clue how. Now it just shows an empty page.
It's not finished yet as i said but i just first want to the CSS done and than do the rest.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
h1 {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
p {
  color: darkred;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
p2 {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
a {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.tabcontent {
  display:none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Bio-informatica')">Bio-informatica</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Leiden')">Leiden</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Baangarantie')">Baangarantie</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Motivatie')">London</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Bio-informatica in het veld')">Bio-informatica in het veld</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Bronvermelding')">Bronvermelding</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Home</h3>
        <img src="Norway.jpeg" class="w3-round-small" alt="Norway" style="width:30%">
    </div>
    <div id="Bio-informatica" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Wat is bio-informatica</h3>
        <p>In het algemeen is bio-informatica de wetenschap die tot doel heeft de biologische kennis te vergroten door aspecten uit informatica toe te passen op data uit het biologische vlak.<br />
        Bio-informatica wordt ook gezien als een van de deelgebieden van de medische informatiekunde, wat betekent: Een interdisciplinair wetenschappelijk vakgebied met het goed<br />
        en snel gebruiken van biologische data en informatie t.b.v. wetenschappelijk research. Een heel groot deel van de aspecten van bio-informatica wordt geleerd bij de opleiding op Hogeschool Leiden.<br />
        Zo leer je programmeren en biologie vanaf de basics met nog een paar extra vakken. Je maakt tijdens het jaar een aantal projecten<br />
        waarbij je de kennis die je leert bij de vakken toepast en dus ook echt in de praktijk je kennis toepast tijdens je studie.</p>
        <p>Bio-informatica is relatief nieuw, dit betekent dat er elke dag nieuwe ontwikkelingen worden gedaan.

        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Leiden" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Baangarantie" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Motivatie" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>London</h3>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Bio-informatica in het veld" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Bronvermelding" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openCity(evt, cityName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

is in the file

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
<buttonclass="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
```

To:

```
<button id="home-button" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
```

You can create a js file and put code(jsFileName.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#home-button").click();
});
```

After create this js file you can should import file in head of your html file

```
<script src="jsFileName.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand it, do i need to put the js file with the code in a folder with the html file? Just like when you want a picture on your website

Comment: Yes. You need to put different files like test.html, test.css, test.js.

Comment: It still isnt working, can you maybe explain it a bit more?